# How to find request initiator of a request with initiator "other"

Tags: javascript, http, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

Is there any to trace the caller stack of a network request with initiator shown as "other" in the network tab?

I tried to search the request param's in the source but I did not find it anywhere.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't test it extensively, but I can say that `Other` is shown in cases when an element like `img` is added dynamically. There could be other cases, of course.

In your case, searching by the domain name reveals one of the requests, Amazon S3 `img` beacon:

```
Unbxd.tracker_url = Unbxd.local === !0 ? "/v2/1p.jpg" : "//tracker.unbxdapi.com/v2/1p.jpg",
.........................................
var i = Unbxd.tracker_url + "?data=" + encodeURIComponent(e) + "&UnbxdKey=" + r + "&action=" + n + "&uid=" + o + "&t=" + (new Date).getTime() + "|" + Math.random()
  , a = new Image;
a.src = i,
```

As you can see 1) the image is not added to DOM, 2) its URL is generated dynamically.
So there's no way to find it by the full request URL in Ctrl-Shift-F Search.
I was just lucky the domain part wasn't obfuscated in the code.